# lack of understanding cnn result and utility

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, mnist

I'm working on deep learning and I think I'm lost in the cnn. Let me explain: by following [Aurélien Géron's github](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/13_convolutional_neural_networks.ipynb) (In cell [21]) I trained "my basic" MNIST . And everything went well ... I think .. ^^ ... I used an initialization of he too.. :

.... 
8 Last batch accuracy: 1.0 Test accuracy: 0.9852, 
9 Last batch accuracy: 1.0 Test accuracy: 0.9892,

However, in the book of the same author, it specifies that: "... once the CNN has learned to recognize a pattern in one location, it can recognize it in any other location ..." (page 358). Does this mean that if my network detects 99% of a digit, I would be able to move it anywhere it recognizes it? I ask this, because it does not work. The predictions are very bad, i.e. 100% detection of a "4" on a 28x28 image:

... 
3 : 0.0 % 
4 : 100.0 % 
5 : 0.0 %
...

On this same image I move the shape of a few pixels (with paint, for those who want to know how):

0 : 20.0 % 
1 : 21.0 % 
2 : 2.0 % 
3 : 0.0 % 
4 : 22.0 % 
5 : 14.0 % 
6 : 0.0 % 
7 : 21.0 % 
8 : 1.0 % 
9 : 0.0 %

Do I really understand the idea of a cnn, or not?
Moreover, why it doesn't work if I put a "4" and a "2" side by side?
The networks aren't supposed to tell me 100% each?

#### My `import_graph` code:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("./my_mnist_model.meta")  
X_prod = snt_X_prod.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 28*28) / 255.0 
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, "./my_mnist_model")
result = sess.run("output/Y_proba:0", feed_dict={"inputs/X:0": X_prod})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not as simple as that. The convolutional **layer** indeed is in a sense invariant to translation of the image, however the neural network that you are using is not just a convolutional layer, from what I can see in the notebook, it contains two convolutional layers, max pooling, fully connected and output layer. The fully connected and output layers are naturally **not** invariant to translation, therefore the whole network is not invariant to translation. When you shift the input image and feed it to the network, the output of the second convolutional layer will be the same as with the original image, just translated accordingly, however, the fully connected layers were trained to "expect" some distribution of activations of the convolutional layer, by translating the image manually you are probably providing an example that is too different from the training examples which results in a failed classification.

For the second point, 4 and 2 side by side doesn't work because the network was not trained on pairs of digits. As in the previous case, when you present the network with a 4 and 2 in a single image, the output of the convolutional layer will be very different from what occured during training, therefore the network won't give you a meaningful answer.

Furthermore, the network has a softmax layer on the top, so in fact it **cannot** give you 100% on two classes at once, the sum of all probabilities will always be 100%.

I recommend trying to get a deeper understanding of what is actually going on in the neural network and how it is optimized. Once you grasp the few clever bits of math that are involved, you will see the answers to your questions. The models are not magic boxes that always give you the right answer. For this I recommend the CNN course from Stanford, by Andrej Karpathy. If you follow that, you will get real, non-superficial understanding of what is going on.

If you want a model that works well on translated digits, you can use larger images, e.g. 40x40, then put the original 28x28 image into a random position and train your network on that. Then you should have a model that can recognize a digit no matter where you put it.

If you want a model, that can recognize multiple digits, create a dataset that contains examples of images with multiple digits and use multiple labels for each sample (for this you will have to stop using softmax and use sigmoid, probably with MSE error instead). Then you should have a model that can recognize multiple digits at once.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed, I did not understand the meaning of convolution Moreover, in hindsight and your answer, many questions come to me (you do not need to answer): why 32 and then 64 cards? Why 64 hidden layers and not me?etc .... Since the beginning, I learn by myself but now, I realize I need to discuss with more experienced people in this area. I will try to find references to Karpathy's classes and look for forums. Anyway, for MNIST, I now understand that this is a "hello world" of ML and that the book is a foretaste intended to give us a head start. Thank you for your help.